# What sort of feedback button should I implement to measure the difficulty of a task

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset

**---background info---**
My company has built a Search Engine Optimisation product that can suggest monthly prioritised SEO activities (task suggestions), that will have the most benefit to the end user.

For my example, let's say we are interested in 10 keywords and 4 task suggestions.

The keywords of interest are: “mortgage, mortgage rate, interest rate, mortgage comparison, loan, loan rates, loan interest, loan interest rate, mortgage calculator, loan repayment calculator”.

The possible task suggestions are:

1. Build a link to this page with relevant anchor text. For example,
   find one website and get them to link to your page so that the link
   contains the words “mortgage calculator”.
2. Produce some content revolving around the keyword: e.g. make a mortgage calculator
   plugin.
3. Modify an on-page attribute, e.g. change the page title
   to contain the word “mortgage calculator”.
4. Generate social media interest: e.g. get people to “like” your mortgage calculator on
   facebook.

With 10 keywords and 4 tasks, there are a total of 40 possible task/keyword suggestions. At the moment the tasks are prioritised using a predetermined “difficulty” rating, based on a poll of search engine optimisation experts.

We would like to collect data and develop an algorithm which will update the difficulty ratings.

There are two reasons for this:

1. Certain tasks might be more difficult for some clients. E.g. if a client does not have someone in charge of social media, it might be hard for them to implement a social media campaign. Therefore, we would like our difficult ratings to reflect our client's specific circumstances
2. We would like to give new clients better info on how difficult a task is based on our current clients' experiences.

**---end background info---**

I have two questions, one related to data collection, and the second related to how the data collected should be analysed.

**Question 1:**
We would like to get user feedback on task difficulty. **What sort of button should I implement to poll users** so that we get useful data which can be used to update our difficulty ratings? Should this button be:

1. Something different to the following options?
2. Yes/no response to the question “Was this task too difficult”.
3. Please rate the difficulty of this task on a scale of 1 to 5.
4. Is this task more difficult than the task above/below it?
5. We already have an option for the user to reject the task. Perhaps we could derive information about difficulty from this?

**Question 2:**
 **What sort of analysis methods can we use to update the difficulty rating?** Does the analysis method differ depending on the way we collect data?

Comment: I hope this question is not too long. Please give me feedback if it is, and I will split it into sub questions. Thanks in advance!